# Different API functionality for different roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have API with asp.net core 2.1. Claims-based authentication. Is it possible to combine these two api function in one?

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[HttpPost("delete")]
public IActionResult Delete([FromBody]Item item)
{
    _itemService.Delete(item.Id);
    return Ok();
}

[Authorize]
[HttpPost("delete")]
public IActionResult Delete([FromBody]Item item)
{
    var id = int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);
    if (_itemService.IsAuthor(id))
    {
        _itemService.Delete(item.Id);
        return Ok();
    }
    return Forbid();
}
```

Or should I just check the role inside method?

Comment: [Resource-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) might be useful here.

Comment: May be having a custom policy with Authorization handler be the best choice in this case. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checking the permission with whether the user is `Admin` or `Author`, you could implement `multiple requirements` as the doc from @user2884707bond.

For using the `multiple requrements` for your scenario.

You could follow steps below:

- `PermissionHandler.cs`

  ```
          public class PermissionHandler : IAuthorizationHandler
  {
      public Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
      {
          var pendingRequirements = context.PendingRequirements.ToList();

          foreach (var requirement in pendingRequirements)
          {
              if (requirement is ReadPermission)
              {
                  if (IsOwner(context.User, context.Resource) ||
                      IsAdmin(context.User, context.Resource))
                  {
                      context.Succeed(requirement);
                  }
              }
              else if (requirement is EditPermission ||
                       requirement is DeletePermission)
              {
                  if (IsOwner(context.User, context.Resource))
                  {
                      context.Succeed(requirement);
                  }
              }
          }
          return Task.CompletedTask;
      }
      private bool IsAdmin(ClaimsPrincipal user, object resource)
      {
          if (user.IsInRole("Admin"))
          {
              return true;
          }
          return false;
      }

      private bool IsOwner(ClaimsPrincipal user, object resource)
      {
          // Code omitted for brevity

          return true;
      }

      private bool IsSponsor(ClaimsPrincipal user, object resource)
      {
          // Code omitted for brevity

          return true;
      }
  }
  ```
- Requirements

  ```
      public class ReadPermission : IAuthorizationRequirement
  {
      // Code omitted for brevity
  }
  public class EditPermission : IAuthorizationRequirement
  {
      // Code omitted for brevity
  }
  public class DeletePermission : IAuthorizationRequirement
  {
      // Code omitted for brevity
  }
  ```
- Register `Requirement` in `Startup.cs`

  ```
          services.AddAuthorization(options =>
      {
          options.AddPolicy("Read", policy => policy.AddRequirements(new ReadPermission()));                
      });
      services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, PermissionHandler>();
  ```
- Use

  ```
   [Authorize(Policy = "Read")]
   [HttpPost("delete")]
   public IActionResult Delete([FromBody]Item item)
   {
        _itemService.Delete(item.Id);
        return Ok();
    }
  ```

Comment: I am wondering if anything need to be implemented within Requirements? or it can be empty? And how to use the resource parameter in IsOwner method? Need to cast it to other class and access the properties inside?