# .Net Core Authorization on data displaying on view

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-authorization

I am trying add an authorization logic to my .net core web based application to allow only the author(recorded in each database record as username) allow for edit/delete kind of action, others only can read.

I did some googling, seems Resource based authorization may suit my requirements:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Not sure if I need to write a lot of handlers to implement the logic as shown in this example?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-2.1

My understanding, the logic is like:

```
If current login user == the created by user in database record
    Display edit/delete link.
    Allow access the edit/delete action method in Controller.
Else
    Access is denied.
```

Should I follow what the sample code's way or write my own authorization class?
And if it is simpler to write my own authorization logic class, how could I invoke the logic as attribute above edit/delete action method in the controller?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Not sure if I need to write a lot of handlers to implement the logic as shown in this example?

There is no need, you could define one `PermissionHandler` which will check the user permission in `HandleAsync`.

> how could I invoke the logic as attribute above edit/delete action method in the controller?

For invoking as attribute, you could try like

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Read")]
[HttpPost("delete")]
public IActionResult Delete([FromBody]Item item)
{
  _itemService.Delete(item.Id);
  return Ok();
}
```

For a complete demo, try to refer [Different API functionality for different roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53186143/different-api-functionality-for-different-roles/53201936#53201936).

Comment: Thank you. I will go through the demo first.

Comment: Thank you Tao, just wonder for the Requirements in your example, do they need to be in a different .cs file or can be within PermissionHandler.cs? And any chance for a simple for the Read or Edit Permission sample? I am still trying to come up with an end to end solution.